# filter() in the javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I have a challenge on Codewar. And below is my solve
but i don't understand why return e and return arr[i-1] both return the same results.

```js
var uniqueInOrder=function(iterable){
  
  let arry = typeof iterable === "string" ? iterable.split('') : iterable;
  
  return arry.filter(function(e,i,arr)
    { 
        if(i === 0)
        {
           console.log(e);
           return e;
        }
        else if(arr[i-1] !== e) 
          {
      
            console.log(arr[i-1] );
            return e;
            //return arr[i-1];
          }
      });
}
uniqueInOrder("aaaabbbccdaabbbab");
```

Answer (score 3):

`filter` creates a new array built from the entries for which your callback returns a truthy value. Your code *always* returns a truthy value, because if `i` is `0` you're returning `e` (one of the characters from the array, all of which are truthy), and if `i` isn't `0` if were using the commented-out `return arr[i-1]`, you'd *also* be returning one of the characters from the array.

So you're not filtering at all, just copying the array.

Comment: Thanks sir. My problem has been resolved.